# Django select only models with different field

Tags: django

I have a model called Product_Variation:

```
class Product_Variation( models.Model ):
    color               = models.ForeignKey('Color', verbose_name="Color", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    size                = models.ForeignKey('Size', verbose_name="Size", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sku                 = models.CharField(verbose_name="SKU", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    main_picture        = FilerImageField(related_name="main_picture", verbose_name="Main Picture", null=True, blank=True)
    image_gallery       = models.ManyToManyField('Media', related_name="image_gallery", verbose_name="Image Gallery", blank=True)
    regular_price       = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Regular Price", null=True, blank=True)
    sale_price          = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Sale Price", null=True, blank=True)
    stock_quantity      = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Stock Quantity", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    weight              = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Weight", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    dimension_length    = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Length", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    dimension_width     = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Width", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    dimension_height    = models.FloatField(verbose_name="Height", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    barcode             = models.CharField(verbose_name="Barcode", max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    priority            = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Priority", null=True, blank=True)
    total_view          = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Total View", default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    total_sales         = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Total Sales", default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)

    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', verbose_name="Product that Variation belongs to", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

How do i get Product_variations that have distinct color? I am using mysql.

I tried:

```
Product_Variation.objects.all().values('product__id', 'color').distinct()
```

but i don't know how to get only the id too, because if i use

```
Product_Variation.objects.all().values('id', 'product__id', 'color').distinct()
```

the distinct does not work anymore because the id are all unique

Comment: Product_Variation.objects.all().values( 'product__id', 'color').distinct().values('id', 'product__id', 'color') ..try this

Comment: nope, weirdly it does the same thing like Product_Variation.objects.all().values('id', 'product__id', 'color').distinct()

Comment: don't use .all() in query, try that

Comment: same thing sadly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
distinct_prod_vars = Product_Variation.objects.all().distinct('color')
```

Comment: I guess you will have to use two querysets to fetch the result you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
distinct_prod_vals = Product_Variation.objects.values('color').distinct()
```

Comment: I tried it. close, but i need the product_variation ID too. Thanks

Comment: i tried Product_Variation.objects.all().values('product__id', 'color').distinct()

but i don't know how to get only the id too, because if i use Product_Variation.objects.all().values('id', 'product__id', 'color').distinct()

the distinct does not work anymore because the id are all unique